# Como usar o SELECT + WHERE + IN do MySQL com array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, angular

Como eu posso realizar a seguinte consulta SQL passando um array de string do JavaScript?

Consulta SQL realizada no MySQL - status OK:

```
SELECT * FROM tab_price_list AS PL
WHERE PL.PartNumber IN ('HDW00008.ELEM', 'HDW00006.ELEM', 'HDW00002.ELEM', 'HDW00004.ELEM')
```

Na minha aplicação o valor dentro dos parênteses será dinâmico e virá do front-end podendo ser um array com 1 ou N elementos, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
ProductsDAO.prototype.getProductData = function (part_numbers_array, callback) {
    this._connection.query(`
        SELECT * FROM tab_price_list as PL 
        WHERE PL.PartNumber IN (?);
    `, part_numbers_array, callback)
}
```

Onde a variável "part_numbers_array" é:

```
part_numbers_array = [
  'HDW00008.ELEM',
  'HDW00006.ELEM',
  'HDW00002.ELEM',
  'HDW00004.ELEM',
]
```

Atualmente esse código está trazendo somente as linhas onde PL.partNumber é igual ao elemento de index 0 do array. Nesse caso, onde PL.partNumber = 'HDW00008.ELEM'.

Como faço para a consultar se feita para todos os elementos do meu array?

Comment: Tem um comando no php que "junta" as strings no array e envia como um dado só.
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);

echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisará inserir os valores diretamente na sua `query`:

```
const parametros = part_numbers_array.map((item) => "'${item}'").join(',');

this._connection.query(`SELECT * FROM tab_price_list as PL  WHERE PL.PartNumber IN (${parametros});`, part_numbers_array, callback);
```

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo eu tenho que mudar "'${item}'" --> `${item}`, certo?

Comment: @LeonardoVinicius não. O `map` é justamente para colocar plicas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas para funcionar foi preciso fazer a seguinte alteração:
const parametros = part_numbers_array.map((item) => `"${item}"`).join(',');
Troquei aspas duplas por crase e funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Acredito que faltou você fazer `part_time_array.join()` na montagem do SQL

Segue um exemplo abaixo

[Querying MySQL using a set of values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203506/querying-mysql-using-a-set-of-values-in-a-javascript-array)